# iPhoto 5: How can I get the top-level display back in rolls (thumbnails) mode?

Tags: macos, iphoto

This is on my parents' PPC, running OSX 10.4.something, and iPhoto 5 (no upgrade
available because they bought the machine 2 weeks before Apple moved to Intel).

They used the prefs to show the # of photos in each album in the left sidebar.
That worked, but now when the click on the Library icon in the sidebar,
iPhoto displays individual photos in the main view, not the rolls or
thumbnails.

I'm ok with issuing a settings command at the command-line, if that's
what it takes to fix the problem.

If you recognize this post from the apple site, good on you, but I'm
betting asking here will be more productive.